# Facebook graph api with 'NATIVE' (no PHP) iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the Facebook Graph API in a NATIVE iPhone Application. I need help to POST images/message on facebook.

I know of these two resources on the net but they do not provide any help with posting on the user's feed.

1. http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api
2. http://blog.corywiles.com/facebook-graph-api-with-a-native-iphone-appli

Comment: Have you looked into the SDK? http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK

Comment: Yes, I have. The link that you provide is for Facebook Connect. Facebook have moved to the graph api now. I am trying to work with the Facebook graph api for this app.
I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's new iOS documentation should help point you in the right direction. See the iOS Scrumptious tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ which walks you through the basics.